# How can I make a table in a cell a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, button, html-table

I have a table in a cell that displays the numbers a user enters with buttons (using onclick and a showthis function. I need to be able to store the value as a variable in order to perform operations on it. How can I do this?
 PS: I am using JavaScript and HTML

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function showthis(first){ 
        document.getElementById("displaycell").innerHTML+=first; 
    } 
</script>
<body> 
  <h1 align="center"> RPN Calculator </h1>
  <table summary align="center" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
      <th id="displaycell" colspan="5" type="text"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button" onclick="showthis('1')">1</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" onclick="showthis('2')">2</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" onclick="showthis('3')">3</button>
     </td>
     <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show? We cannot help if we don't know what we are working with.

Comment: I think the HTML needs to be fixed (the `<th>` should *not* be closed by a `</td>`). I'd do it myself, but I don't know if that's the real HTML, or a typo here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should not be using `+=` with `innerHTML`. It means that you will end up with the numbers appending to the cell's internal value rather than overwriting it.

```
function showthis ( number ) {
    var cell = document.getElementById('displaycell');
    cell.innerHTML = "";
    cell.appendChild( document.createTextNode( number ));
}
```

Would be a much better way to handle that.

Next, within showthis you are best off storing the value in a variable so that you can access it directly from javascript in the future.

```
var displayStore = 0;

function showthis ( number ) {
    var cell = document.getElementById('displaycell');
    cell.innerHTML = "";
    cell.appendChild( document.createTextNode( number ));

    // you can either do this in a variable local to the <td> DOM Object like so
    cell.currentDisplayNumber = number;

    //or in a global variable like so
    displayStore = number;
}
```

Finally, to access that variable again you can either read it out of the `displaystore <td>` or read it from your variable.

```
function DoStuff0 () {
    var number = Number( document.getElementById( 'displaycell' )).innerHTML;
    // rest
}

function DoStuff1 () {
    var number = document.getElementById('displaycell').currentDisplayNumber;
    // rest
} 

function DoStuff2 () {
    var number = displayStore;
    // rest
}
```

Comment: <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function showthis(first){
document.getElementById("displaycell").innerHTML+=first;

}


</script>

<body>

<h1 align="center"> RPN Calculator </h1>

<table summary align="center" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3">

<tr> 
<th id="displaycell" colspan="5" type="text"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> <button type="button" onclick="showthis('1')">1</button> </td>
<td> <button type="button" onclick="showthis('2')">2</button> </td>
<td> <button type="button" onclick="showthis('3')">3</button> </td>

Comment: put the code in your question, not as a comment. It is useless in this form.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/CWQY2/

HTML:

```
<h1 align="center"> RPN Calculator </h1>
<table summary align="center" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <th id="displaycell" colspan="5"> </th> 
    </tr> 

    <tr> 
        <td> <button type="button" onClick="showthis('1')">1</button> </td> 
        <td> <button type="button" onClick="showthis('2')">2</button> </td> 
        <td> <button type="button" onClick="showthis('3')">3</button> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function showthis(first){ 
    document.getElementById("displaycell").innerHTML += first; 
}
​
```

​